# Git rebase interactive edit for merged feature branches?

Tags: git, merge, git-rebase

What will happen in the following scenario:

- There is a master branch with endless lifeline
- New branches are created for features and merged with master when finished. The branch is afterwords deleted

At some point i needed to do a change in the feature that was already considered closed (it was merged into master and deleted)

```
      X --- --- (feature (branch deleted)
     /         \                
    /           \              
   a --- --- --- M master
```

What I did was:

```
git rebase --interactive X
```

Did the changes in the source and amended the commit X. I was hoping to have the graph unchanged but got something like:

```
        X --- -(feature (branch deleted)
       /      \
      /        M
     /        /
    /        /                 
   a --- --- --- X master
```

Does the editing of commits spread between merges? What about potential conflicts with existing "future" commits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new commit graph has another `X` commit because rebase does not preserve merges by default. If you wanted to preserve merges, you need to use the `--preserve-merges` flag, or `-p` for short:

```
git rebase -i -p <base-commit>
```

**Note that [preserving merges interactively does not work correctly when you reorder commits](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html#bugs).** It's OK to use them together otherwise:

> The todo list presented by `--preserve-merges` `--interactive` does not
>   represent the topology of the revision graph. Editing commits and rewording
>   their commit messages should work fine, but attempts to reorder commits tend
>   to produce counterintuitive results.

Also, are you sure that `X` was the base commit you wanted to use? If you wanted to amend `X`, I think you should have chosen `a` as the base instead:

```
git rebase -i -p a
```

Comment: `X` had the changes that were related to the branch, that's why i choose it.

Comment: @Alan when you use rebase, you're supposed to invoke it with a base commit ***that won't change***, which means you have to choose the commit ***right before*** the commit that you're going to modify. Does `X` show up in the interactive rebase editor, where you pick, edit, and squash commits from?