# Git rebase -i --preserve-merges loses changes

Tags: git

I have the follwing situation:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.7.3.windows.1

$ git log --graph --oneline
* 83e3254 version 1.1
*   34188af merge of feature into master
|\
| * 784ba31 awesome change
|/
* 6eec273 added file1
* 84d80a5 added version file
```

To reproduce this **in a new directory**

```
rm -rf .git
git init
echo version 1.0 > version.txt
git add version.txt
git commit -m "added version file"

echo file1 > file1
git add file1
git commit -m "added file1"

git checkout -b feature
echo awesome change >> file1 && git commit -am "awesome change"

git checkout master
git merge --no-ff --no-commit feature
echo "small fixup" >> file1
git commit -am "merge of feature into master"

echo version 1.1 > version.txt
git commit -am "version 1.1"
```

Now I saw this feature was meant for version 1.1. So I did this:

```
git rebase --preserve-merges -i master~3
```

with this as git-rebase-todo

```
pick 6eec273 added file1
pick 83e3254 version 1.1
pick 784ba31 awesome change
pick 34188af merge of feature into master
```

and got this:

```
$ git log --graph --oneline
*   34188af merge of feature into master
|\
| * 784ba31 awesome change
|/
* 6eec273 added file1
* 84d80a5 added version file
```

what happened to 83e3254? Have I missed something? Should I use 34188af in the todofile when I need to preserve merges?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably related with the documented imperfectness of the rebase mechanism. From the [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) documentation:

> ```
> -p
> --preserve-merges
> ```
>
> Recreate merge commits instead of flattening the history by replaying commits a merge commit introduces. Merge conflict
>   resolutions or manual amendments to merge commits are not preserved.
>
> This uses the `--interactive` machinery internally, but **combining it with the `--interactive` option explicitly is generally not a good idea**
>   unless you know what you are doing (see BUGS below).

The `-i` and `--interactive` options are synonymous.

Let’s see the BUGS section:

> The todo list presented by `--preserve-merges --interactive` does not
>   represent the topology of the revision graph. Editing commits and
>   rewording their commit messages should work fine, but attempts to
>   reorder commits tend to produce counterintuitive results.
>
> For example, an attempt to rearrange
>
> ```
> 1 --- 2 --- 3 --- 4 --- 5
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> 1 --- 2 --- 4 --- 3 --- 5
> ```
>
> by moving the "pick 4" line will result in the following history:
>
> ```
>         3
>        /
> 1 --- 2 --- 4 --- 5
> ```

Comment: Good to know that this is a known issue. But I really would like to have a warning or even error if a commit is missing after the rebase that was in the pick list. Thanks
Similar SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23262224/git-rebase-interactive-edit-for-merged-feature-branches

Answer (score 5):

[Melebius' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40780917/1256452) is correct (and upvoted); it has to do with the way interactive rebase tries to replay the commits as a series of cherry-picks.  Since a merge is not actually a cherry-pick, the preserve-merge mode uses a secret side channel<sup>1</sup> to figure out how to *re-perform* merges, and this side channel depends on the commit ordering.

There is, however, another problem with re-performing a merge.  The merge is redone by running `git merge`.  Here is your original merge:

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff --no-commit feature
echo "small fixup" >> file1             # DANGER WILL ROBINSON
git commit -am "merge of feature into master"
```

(note my added remark).  This "small fixup" is not part of the two inputs: it was added manually via the `--no-commit` feature and, well, manual manipulation.  This is sometimes called an "evil merge":

- [Evil merges in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461909/1256452)
- [How do you detect an evil merge in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27683077/1256452)
- [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12615932/1256452) to [Evil merges in git - where do they come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3069764/1256452) (which links to and includes Junio C Hamano's explanation of why evil merges are sometimes good).

When `git rebase -p` "replays" the merge, it does so *without* `--no-commit`, and then *automatically moves on* to the next linearized commit.  So any changes deliberately introduced like this will be lost, even if you preserve the commit ordering and hence get an otherwise correct rebased history.

This *is* documented—see the quoted text, which says:

> Merge conflict resolutions or manual amendments to merge commits are not preserved.

—but in my opinion this sentence needs to be in bold blinking 72-point font or something. :-)

---

<sup>1</sup>It's not really very secret at all: simply view the interactive rebase code.  Using your file viewer or editor, look at `$(git --exec-path)/git-rebase--interactive`.  Search for the string "preserv" (as in preserve or preserving) and observe the function `pick_one_preserving_merges` and the code in `pick_one` that calls it if a directory named `$rewritten` exists.  The usage of the `$rewritten` directory is rather complex, though (it applies to both merge-preserving and non-merge-preserving interactive rebases and relies on the fact that *without* the `--preserve` or `-p` option, the initial "todo" list contains no actual merges and therefore simply flattens them away).

Comment: Great answer +1, my new rule is: Avoid evil merges, haven't thought about the consequences before.